# Flot chart ajax dynamic url getting data from server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, flot

As I see to the flot [reference](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md). 
they said,

> The plot function can also be used as a jQuery chainable property.

Is possible to define the flot chart to be like this?

```
var pid = '';
var kid = '';
var chartasset;

$(document).ready(function() {
 var optionchart = {
  series: {
   pie: {
    show: true,                
    label: {
     show:true,
     radius: 0.8,
     formatter: function (label, series) {                
      return '<div style="border:1px solid grey;font-size:8pt;text-align:center;padding:5px;color:white;">' + label + ' : ' + Math.round(series.percent) + '%</div>';
     },
     background: {
      opacity: 0.8,
      color: '#000'
     }
    }
   }
  }
 };

 chartasset = $('#chartasset').plot({
  "ajax" : {
   "url": "<?php echo site_url('Asset/chart_asset')?>?pid="+pid+"&kid="+kid,
   "type": "POST",
   "cache": false,
   "dataType": "json"
  }, optionchart}).data('plot');
});
```

I need to make the url dynamically change in another function, so I can use :

```
chartasset.ajax.url("<?php echo site_url('Asset/chart_asset')?>?pid="+pid+"&kid="+kid).load();
```

How can I use the flot chainable property to get the data, after I'm defining the flot? Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What actually happen? R u not getting values in php

Comment: the chart is blank, no label no chart, and not getting the ajax on document ready

Comment: F12, Developer's Inspector => Console. There are errors shown.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not define the Flot chart like that. If you want to use AJAX, do it this way (`result` has to be in the right [format](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format)):

```
$.ajax({
    "url": "<?php echo site_url('Asset/chart_asset')?>?pid="+pid+"&kid="+kid,
    "type": "POST",
    "cache": false,
    "dataType": "json",
    success: function(result) {
        chartasset = $('#chartasset').plot(result, optionchart).data('plot');
    }
}
```